# GIT Branch revision in repository

Tags: github

How can we know if the local master is behind remote master in repo with out pulling or fetching.

I mean before pulling or fetching, I would like to determine if my local master is behind repo master so that I can perform fetch / rebase / merge if it is behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way that I know of. If you fetch, you don't have to rebase immediately and then "git status" will tell you if you're ahead or behind (or both). You'd have to do some kind of "remote query" to get the information you want - and fetch is that query.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` is for this very particular purpose. It updates the tracking branches so that you know how far/behind your branch is as compared to remote branch. It does not merge/apply the changes in the remote to your local branch. `git pull` does that.

And that is the difference between `git pull` and `git fetch`

Comment: What happen to "without pulling or fetching"? "before pulling or fetching"?

Comment: I think the person asking the question was confused about the working of `git fetch` and `git pull`. So, I just thought of clarifying it because `git fetch` would solve the problem in the question.

Comment: No, the person was *not* confused: the question was: "*without* fetching". You did not answer the question.

Comment: Why would anyone want to over complicate things when the same could be done in a simpler manner?

Comment: That is a legitimate question that you are asking. It is *not* the one asked by the OP though.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. 

All OP wanted to do was to know whether his local branch was _behind_ of the remote one so that _He can perform fetch / rebase / merge if it is behind_. 

You went with the _words_ of OP and chose to provide a solution which _you thought_ he wanted. 

Whereas I chose to provide a solution which was simplistic and what he needed.

Comment: I was not confused. I want to check if my branch is behind or not and if behind, then only run the fetch /merge / rebase commands. Else, do nothing.

Comment: @VonC the above comments is the proof that the OP was confused

Comment: @Rams the confusion we are talking here is that whether you deliberately wanted to not do `fetch` for knowing that your branch was behind the `remote` branch.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to contact the remote repo in some way.

The only command that can give you an hint is [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html)

```
git ls-remote origin
```

More precisely, compare:

```
git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master 
git rev-list --max-count=1 origin/master
```

If the SHA1 returned for the master branch differs from the one you have locally, your branch might be behind (or ahead if that SHA1 is accessible from your local branch HEAD)

At least, with `git ls-remote`, you don't fetch all repo.